# How do I change Windows 10 cursor to run between both monitors?

Tags: windows, control-panel, cursor

First, how do I change my mouse back to one cursor controlling both of my two monitors and moving freely between both monitors? Now there is one cursor on each screen and neither cursor will move between the screens. Second, how do bring back the Control Panel? I has disappeared.

Comment: It sounds like you have your monitors set to duplicate rather than extend. Is that right, both monitors have the same content?  Please limit your question to one subject, open another question for the Control Panel issue and please  make sure you include far more detail than you have - such as how are trying to get to Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your display settings to "duplicate' instead of extended mode. To change back do the following:

Close all open programs.

Right-click an empty area on your desktop, and click Display Settings

Click the Multiple Displays drop-down list, and select  Extend these displays

[image]